# WS_EX_COMPOSITED style in ListView causes endless WM_PAINT

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to give the custom border color for the ListView in C#. I have subclassed the ListView and override the WndProc method to handle the WM_NCPAINT message to give the custom border color.

```
public class SampleListView : ListView
  {
      public SampleListView ()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         View = Details.Details;
      }
      protected override CreateParams CreateParams
       {
          get
          {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; /*WS_EX_COMPOSITED*/
            return cp;
          }
        }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case: WM_NCPAINT
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                    IntPtr hDc=Win32.GetWindowDC(m.Hwnd);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(hDc);
                RECT windowRect= new RECT();
                Win32.GetWindoRect(m.Hwnd, ref windowRect);
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, windowRect, Color.YellowGreen, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

                g.Dispose();
                break;                
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Add SampleListView to the form and start the application. The SPY++ shows a infinite WM_PAINT loop in SampleListView. Is this a bug???
I am using WS_EX_COMPOSITED style  to avoid the filckering. How can I avoid this a infinite WM_PAINT loop?

Comment: That style flag is only appropriate on top-level windows.  Avoiding flicker on a ListView is already very simple, just set its DoubleBuffered property to *true*.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to know why you use `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`. I expect that's the wrong solution to some other problem. Or perhaps an attempt to deal with the current problem. I don't see any obvious reason why you'd need that style.

One wonders why you don't use `GetDCEx` to get a DC. One also wonders why you pass a DC to `Graphics.FromHwnd` which expects a window handle. Presumably this results in an exception and perhaps that's your infinite loop.

What you should be doing is calling `GetDCEx` to obtain the device context. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212.aspx) for more details on that. Then `Graphics.FromHdc` to get a `Graphics` object. Remember to call `ReleaseDC` when you are done with the DC.